# boost::regex performance issue

Tags: c++, regex, boost, boost-regex

I am using boost::regex to find a delimiter in a string (in c++) and replace it with a different one if exist:

```
const boost::regex esc(delimiter);
const std::string rep = "\\\\" + delimiter;

dest += boost::regex_replace(str, esc, rep,
            boost::match_default | boost::format_sed);
```

But when using boost::regex I have a huge decrease in performance (about 50%).

Does anyone know why? Is this a know issue?

Comment: 50% performance decrease compared to what?

Answer (score -1):

We have, in recent times, rolled our own, state-machine based pattern matching routine, having figured out `regex` was slow. Does that help?